# GeoIPIPSP.dat Invalid datebase type

Tags: python, geoip, maxmind

we have a commercial maxmind-subscribtion to obtain a GeoIP-Database with ISP-information (GeioIPIPSP.dat). However, when I try to query this file, I keep getting the following error:

```
GeoIPError: Invalid database type, expected Org, ISP or ASNum
```

I'm using the python-api:

```
geo = GeoIP.open("/GeoIPIPSP.dat", GeoIP.GEOIP_STANDARD)
isp = geo.name_by_addr(ip) # or isp_by_addr with pygeoip
```

When I use the api to ask for the database-type (geo._type) I get "1" ... the same value I get when I open a regular GeoIP.dat. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with GeoIPISP.dat, but it's the most recent file from maxmind's customer-download-page.

Any insights greatly appreciated!

Comment: As we don't have the file this question is impossible to answer... As a paying customer you should probably contact Maxmind support...

Comment: This works for me with the latest version of `GeoIPISP.dat` (20140318). What is the build date for your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a problem with the database-file indeed. After a re-download everything works as it is supposed to.

I switched to pygeoip though and access the database like this:

import pygeoip
geo_isp = pygeoip.GeoIP("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPIPSP.dat")
isp = geo_isp.isp_by_addr("8.8.8.8")